# С++Builder, Visual C++

Tags: c++

Посоветуйте пожалуйста книги по системному программированию на C++Builder и Visual C++

Comment: Что конкретно будете "системно-программировать"?
Драйвера, утилиты для настройки системы и т.п.?

Answer (score 1):

1. Никита Культин С++ Builder в задачах и примерах "БХВ Петербург" 2005
2. Андрей Боровский Самоучитель С++ и  Borland C++ BUILDER ПИТЕР 2005
3. Я М Глинский, В Э Анохин, В А Ряжська С++ & C++ Builder Львов - 2006
4. Никита Культин Самоучитель С++ Builder
    Также, ищите в Сети.
   С уважением, Саша